# Looking for the simplest way to wrap a provided Setup.exe installer with a config.dat and a silent installation CLI execution

Tags: windows, installation, executable, wrapper, silent

I am not familiar with Windows installer builder tools, other than having a conceptual understanding of them. I have a hopefully simple installer-file-wrapping-problem to solve where i would need some advice from people who know this field better than myself:

- I have a vendor provided vanilla Setup.exe installer along with a custom config.dat file.
- I can run the installer with "Setup.exe /S" which picks up the config.dat file in the same directory for a silent install just as I need it.
- I now want to wrap both files into a single file self executable installer "CustomSetup.exe" that if launched with "Run as Administrator" silently unpacks the two files into the same directory, runs the silent install command line "Setup.exe /S" and deletes the previously unpacked files and directory afterwards. Effectively giving me a single-file one-click silent installer with custom settings from the vendor provided vanilla installer.

What is the simplest, most straight forward and elegant way of getting this done?

Most InstallShield/WIX/Windows Installer Tools tutorial- and documentation-pages i could find want to take me to an elaborate installer-project-building-academy first, something that is certainly useful for developers needing to learn how to build complex installer projects, but feels like overkill for just getting this seemingly simple thing done. Is there a lean way to do this? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I have found the answer to my own question.

Running the Windows on-board IExpress (as Administrator) easily produced exactly what I was after. Just type "Iexpress" into the command search box, run as Administraor and fidlle with it. Alternatively, this is someones Video explaining it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXZyq0cMuKI